# This simple code should produce a white screen in the emulator can't figure out why it's not working

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(),
);
}
}
```

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 1220 pos 12: 'renderObject.child == child': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib/main.dart:10
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
Tried to build dirty widget in the wrong build scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand but I clicked on start debugging and then it just worked. So I guess that means there's nothing wrong.